# Set the initial state of the QuantumCircuit using the Statevector object

Tags: qiskit, programming

Suppose we have a 4-qubit quantum state `state` which is a Statevector object:

```
>>> type(state)
qiskit.quantum_info.states.statevector.Statevector
```

I would like to initialize a 6-qubit `QuantumCircuit`, such that registers 0, 1, 3, 4 are initialized in `state`, something like this:

```
qc = QuantumCircuit(6)
qc.initialize(state, [0, 1, 3, 4])
```

Now, the `initialize` method takes a list of complex amplitudes as an input. However, is there a way to feed it `state` directly, without converting it into a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `QuantumCircuit.prepare_state` or `QuantumCircuit.initialize`.

I'll show a simple example.

```python
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.quantum_info import Statevector

state = Statevector.from_label("+-rl")
qc = QuantumCircuit(4)
qc.prepare_state(state, [0, 1, 2, 3])
```

Here I've constructed my `Statevector` object using [Statevector.from_label](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.quantum_info.Statevector.html#qiskit.quantum_info.Statevector.from_label) but you should be able to construct it however you like and plug it into `QuantumCircuit.prepare_state`.

`QuantumCircuit.initialize` resets all qubits to the $|0\rangle$ state before state preparation.

`QuantumCircuit.prepare_state` does not add resets.

Comment: It looks like we can use `state` directly, whether it is `prepare_state` or `initialize`, but why does it matter if `initialize` resets all states to $|0 \rangle$ before preparation?

Comment: Yes, indeed you can do it with `qiskit.initialize`. Adding resets to reset each qubit to the $|0\rangle$ state is in general a non-unitary operation. This is what `QuantumCircuit.initialize` does. If you use `QuantumCircuit.prepare_state` the entire circuit is unitary.

Comment: I'm not quite clear on what you're asking. You can pass a `Statevector` object directly into `QuantumCircuit.initialize`. You don't have to pass a list of amplitudes.